# Javascript: How do I retain a reference to a request initiator in a handler?

Tags: javascript, ajax, design-patterns

I'm not a Javascript person normally, but I've been diving in, reading [Douglas Crockford's book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748), and writing some trivial, useful tidbits as Chrome extensions and [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) (note that this question isn't about either of them).

Right now, I'm trying to figure out how to retain a reference to an object that's initiating an AJAX request, that is: once I set the onload event handler (this is from inside a Chrome extension, so I'm using the base XMLHttpRequest object), is there any way that I can refer back to `MyObject` in the following example:

```
MyObject.prototype = {
    PerformAction: function() {
        this.Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.Request.open("GET", this.ConstructUrl(), true);
        // From within ActionResultHandler, 'this' will always be the XMLHttpRequest
        this.Request.onload = this.ActionResultHandler,
        this.Request.send(null);
    }
}
```

Doing this exactly is going to assign `this` to be the request object itself, and if I simply introduce a wrapper:

```
this.Request.onload = function() { ActionResultHandler() };
```

well, that just isn't going to do *anything*, because the ActionResultHandler is now out of scope.  The reason I'm asking here is because I've only found trivial cases of caller manipulation (e.g. manipulating what `this` refers to from inside a function), but given that OO-ified Javascript and AJAX are literally everywhere, this has to have to be a known, simple issue, but my Google-fu is failing me here. In C#, events are invoked in the context of whoever attaches to them, not the object firing the event, so this doesn't come up on a daily basis. Perhaps there's a much better JS pattern that avoids this issue entirely?

Comment: I'm really too late in the evening (read: drunk) to answer your question properly, but perhaps you can enjoy these articles: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/ and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: see [Function.prototype.bind](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=function.prototype.bind&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018943/javascript-object-binding-problem-inside-of-function-prototype-definitions/3019431#3019431

Comment: As much as I love quirksmode.org, that link doesn't actually cover apply/call, which is what I needed (though the first one does). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear to me which variable you want to hold a reference to.  Here's how you would retain a reference to `MyObject` in your onload handler:

```
MyObject.prototype = {
    PerformAction: function() {
        var MyObjectRef = MyObject,
            ActionResultHandler = this.ActionResultHandler;

        this.Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.Request.open("GET", this.ConstructUrl(), true);
        // From within ActionResultHandler, 'this' will always be the XMLHttpRequest
        this.Request.onload = function () {
                ActionResultHandler.apply(MyObjectRef, arguments);
            };
        this.Request.send(null);
    }
}
```

**Edited**

Ok, I reread your question again and it seems that you want to execute ActionResultHandler in the context of MyObject, so I tweaked my code to do this.

Comment: Indeed that is what I wanted--I settled on assigning the handler this way: `this.Request.onload = function (event) { responder.apply(selfReference, [event, this]); },` in order to preserve both the `XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent` and the `XMLHttpRequest`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried...

```
this.Request.onload = this.ActionResultHandler.apply(this);
```

I'm thinking that's what you're looking for (sorry if it's not). Using `.apply(this)` will point `ActionResultHandler` to `Object`.

Check out [this article](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/) on binding while you're at it! It helped me out a lot.

Comment: Your snippet actually sets `this.Request.onload` to be equal to the return value of `this.ActionResultHandler` called in the context of `this`.  I don't think that's what he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: AFAIK, `this.ActionResultHandler` would always be bound using the present value of `this`..nevertheless, it was on the right track, and the link did help, thanks!