# 'this' is undefined in JavaScript class methods

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I'm new to JavaScript. New as far as all I've really done with it is tweaked existing code and wrote small bits of jQuery.

Now I'm attempting to write a "class" with attributes and methods, but I'm having trouble with the methods. My code:

```
function Request(destination, stay_open) {
    this.state = "ready";
    this.xhr = null;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.stay_open = stay_open;

    this.open = function(data) {
        this.xhr = $.ajax({
            url: destination,
            success: this.handle_response,
            error: this.handle_failure,
            timeout: 100000000,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
        });
    };

    /* snip... */

}

Request.prototype.start = function() {
    if( this.stay_open == true ) {
        this.open({msg: 'listen'});
    } else {

    }
};
//all console.log's omitted
```

The problem is, in `Request.prototype.start`, `this` is undefined and thus the if statement evaluates to false. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason you have `start` in the `prototype`?

Comment: What's `Request.prototype` set to?

Comment: I had a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198264/javascript-how-do-i-retain-a-reference-to-a-request-initiator-in-a-handler in which there are a bunch of helpful links. The crux of it is that `this` in JavaScript is _not_ a constant reference to the 'owner' of a prototypal function being called, like it would be in most OO languages like Java.

Comment: @Matt: Request is a constructor function. Request.prototype defaults to `new Object()`. Anything you add to it automatically becomes properties of objects created using `new Request()`.

Comment: @Matt Ball `Request.prototype` is where instances of `Request` inherit from. In this case it is probably `Function` or `Object`.

Comment: @Chetan and @indie: I know how prototypes work in JavaScript, but I'm asking about _this_ object's prototype. Perhaps the OP has not shown all the code.

Comment: Sorry, yes, this is all the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I mean, that question was asked 3 years later than this one

Answer (score 86, accepted):

How are you calling the start function?

This should work (**new** is the key)

```
var o = new Request(destination, stay_open);
o.start();
```

If you directly call it like `Request.prototype.start()`, `this` will refer to the global context (`window` in browsers).

Also, if `this` is undefined, it results in an error. The if expression does not evaluate to false.

**Update**: `this` object is not set based on declaration, but by *invocation*. What it means is that if you assign the function property to a variable like `x = o.start` and call `x()`, `this` inside start no longer refers to `o`. This is what happens when you do `setTimeout`. To make it work, do this instead:

```
 var o = new Request(...);
 setTimeout(function() { o.start(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: I am using setTimeout: `var listen = new Request(destination, stay_open); setTimeout(listen.start, 500);`

Comment: This saved my life, upon trying to understand why the function I was passing to express' [basicAuth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth) was not working with the same output.

Comment: Or do `o.start.bind(o)`. Why doesn't `x = o.start; x()` work?

Comment: `.bind()` returns a new function, not working in-place. So you'd have to do `x = o.start.bind(o); x()` or `o.start = o.start.bind(o); x=o.start; x()`

Answer (score 189):

I just wanted to point out that sometimes this error happens because a function has been passed as an argument to a high order function and then the scope of `this` got lost. In such cases, I would recommend passing such function bound to `this`. E.g.

```
this.myFunction.bind(this)
```

In addition, a lambda function works:

```
(args) => this.myFunction(args)
```

Comment: Good explanation !! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: there is no telling how much headache you just saved me

Comment: Why does the scope of `this` get lost?

Comment: Good question! I hope this helps: https://eliux.github.io/javascript/common-errors/why-this-gets-undefined-inside-methods-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct anwer! Why isn't this accepted?

Comment: This happens a lot in Modules, which have no 'this' by default... you have to make a `this`, typically an instance of somebody's daughter

Comment: Or you can use an arrow function then you won't have to call the bind.

Comment: I've seen this `bin` function often as a fix for an unexpected behavior of `js`, but _not once_ as a useful feature in any project whatsoever. 100% it's used to bind what you thought it was bound to in the first place.

Comment: Is there a way I can implement my class (using the `class` keyword) without loosing this when the object's function gets passed around?

Comment: @DarkTrick The solution is not in the implementation of the `class`, but how we invoke a function. So, keep creating your class as usual, but when you pass their functions/methods as high order functions use `bind` or an arrow function(lambda).

Answer (score 45):

None of the previous answers had the full solution for me, so posting mine here.

I had a class, which was returning an error when I ran `forEach` on the method reference.

e.g.

```js
class Foo {
  hello (name) {
    return `hello ${name}`
  }

  doGreet (name) {
    return console.log(this.hello(name)) // <- 'this' is undefined
  }
}

// print some names...
const foo = new Foo();
(['nick', 'john']).forEach(foo.doGreet)

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined
//     at doGreet (/.../test.js:7:17)
```

The solution was to the bind the context of the method's `this` within a constructor. i.e.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this.doGreet = this.doGreet.bind(this) // <- Add this
  }

  hello (name) {
    return `hello ${name}`
  }

  doGreet (name) {
    return console.log(this.hello(name))
  }
}
```

Comment: PSA: I tried to do a bunch of shortcuts to automate this or make it less cumbersome. Unfortunately `Object.keys(this)` inside the constructor wasn't able to find all the keys on the object. The best I could do was this: `const bind = (key) => { this[key] = this[key].bind(this) }` Then call `bind('hello'); bind('doGreet')` for each method name manually :(

Comment: @DanielTonon [See my answer :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72197516/8374115)

Comment: @WalterWoshid nice solution! Will give it a go.

Comment: Allelouia ! That works ! Thank you so much !

Comment: You're a lifesaver, man javascript is stupid sometimes

Comment: How would you accomplish this if `doGreet` is a private method (`#doGreet`)? I get an error saying private methods are not writable.

Comment: @Martin_W javascript doesn't have a `private` accessor keyword... can you share a code snippet?

Comment: Example: `class Example { #privateFunc(arg1) { return \`Hello ${arg1}!\`; } method1() { this.#privateFunc = this.#privateFunc.bind(this); const localFunc = this.#privateFunc.bind(this); console.log('This is only a test.'); } }`. Attempting to assign to `this.#privateFunc` will fail, but assigning to `const localFunc` is fine.

Comment: Private class methods are explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_methods

Comment: Looks like a solution for private functions is to define a "shadow" private function and combine it with a private variable: `class Example2 { constructor() { this.#privateFn = this.#shadowFn.bind(this); } #privateFun = null; #shadowFn(arg1) { /* actual function code */ return \`Hello ${arg1}!\`; } }`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin_W - today I learned something new!

Answer (score 18):

JavaScript's OOP is a little funky (or a lot) and it takes some getting used to. This first thing you need to keep in mind is that *there are no Classes* and thinking in terms of classes can trip you up. And in order to use a method attached to a Constructor (the JavaScript equivalent of a Class definition) you need to instantiate your object. For example:

```
Ninja = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};
aNinja = new Ninja('foxy');
aNinja.name; //-> 'foxy'

enemyNinja = new Ninja('boggis');
enemyNinja.name; //=> 'boggis'
```

Note that `Ninja` instances have the same properties but `aNinja` cannot access the properties of `enemyNinja`. (This part should be really easy/straightforward) Things get a bit different when you start adding stuff to the `prototype`:

```
Ninja.prototype.jump = function () {
   return this.name + ' jumped!';
};
Ninja.prototype.jump(); //-> Error.
aNinja.jump(); //-> 'foxy jumped!'
enemyNinja.jump(); //-> 'boggis jumped!'
```

Calling this directly will throw an error because `this` only points to the correct object (your "Class") when the Constructor is instantiated (otherwise it points to the global object, `window` in a browser)

Answer (score 10):

Use arrow function:

```
Request.prototype.start = () => {
    if( this.stay_open == true ) {
        this.open({msg: 'listen'});
    } else {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 8):

In ES2015 a.k.a ES6, `class` is a syntactic sugar for `functions`.

If you want to force to set a context for `this` you can use `bind()` method. As @chetan pointed, on invocation you can set the context as well! Check the example below:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    switch (e.target.id) {
      case 'owner':
        this.setState({owner: e.target.value});
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleNewCodeBlock}>
        <p>Owner:</p> <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Here we forced the context inside `handleChange()` to `Form`.

Comment: You should bind the function to this in the constructor. Otherwise you're binding it every time `render` is called instead of once when the class is instantiated. Also, most of your example is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Or use the arrow syntax when defining the `handleChange()`

Answer (score 4):

This question has been answered, but maybe this might someone else coming here.

I also had an issue where `this` is undefined, when I was foolishly trying to destructure the methods of a class when initialising it:

```js
import MyClass from "./myClass"

// 'this' is not defined here:
const { aMethod } = new MyClass()
aMethod() // error: 'this' is not defined

// So instead, init as you would normally:
const myClass = new MyClass()
myClass.aMethod() // OK
```

Answer (score 4):

If a function has been used as a high order function (passed as an argument) the scope of `this` gets lost.

To fix this problem one can bind `this` to the function like @Eliux described:

```js
this.myFunction.bind(this);
```

To automate this process like @DanielTonon wanted you can do this in the constructor:

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(YourClass.prototype).forEach((key) => {
  if (key !== 'constructor') {
    this[key] = this[key].bind(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: Does this suffice? The autobind library uses more code (including Reflect). Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74369964/6702598

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while passing a catch-handler for a promise.

```
class foo {

   catchHandler(error){
     // do something with this
   }
  
   async myFunction(){
       let x = await somePromise.catch(this.catchHandler);
   }
}
```

I was trying to bind the catchHandler-Function to `this` and i still got the error. What finally fixed it for me was not just pass the function as an argument but using a arrow-Function as a 'wrapper':

```
class foo {

   constructor(){
     this.catchHandler.bind(this); // <--
   }

   catchHandler(error){
     // do something with this
   }
  
   async myFunction(){
      --> let x = await somePromise.catch(e => this.catchHandler(e)); // <--
   }
}
```

This might not help OP but when you encounter the problem as stated in the Question-Header