# Resizing HTML5 canvas via a class method in response to a resize event

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to resize a canvas element via a `resizeCanvas()` method in response to a resize event. The canvas resizes if I call the class method directly, but I get the following error in subsequent calls through the event handler: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined`

Here is my test code:

```js
class CanvasManager {
  constructor(canvasID) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  }

  resizeCanvas() {
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth-30;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight-30;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}

let canvasManager = new CanvasManager('controller');
canvasManager.resizeCanvas();
window.addEventListener("resize", canvasManager.resizeCanvas);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="controller" style="border-style: solid;" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the error?

edit: As `Heretic Monkey` points out, this issue is similar to ['this' is undefined in JavaScript class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54894329/resizing-html5-canvas-via-a-class-method-in-response-to-a-resize-event). However, as a new coder, I would have never figured out both issues were related. I think this post should remain in case someone else has a similar problem can cannot figure out the underlying issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['this' is undefined in JavaScript class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011793/this-is-undefined-in-javascript-class-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of the context of the word `this`. Please, try to replace:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", canvasManager.resizeCanvas);
```

With:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", canvasManager.resizeCanvas.bind(canvasManager));
```

Comment: Also, this would work: window.addEventListener("resize", () => canvasManager.resizeCanvas())