# Calling class methods within jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some javascript class and in one method I use jQuery to bind function to click event. And within this function I need to call other methods of this class. In usual js function I did it through `"this.method_name()"`, but here, I guess, jQuery  redefines "this" pointer.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you pasted a short code snippet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

jQuery doesn't redefine the `this` pointer, but that's how JavaScript functions work in general. Store a reference to the this pointer under a different name, and use that.

```
var self = this;
$("selector").click(function() {
    self.method_name();
});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349380/jquery-proxy-usage/3349438#3349438) for more approaches.

Comment: @Tramp - you're welcome. But note that this is still a hacky approach.  Instead use `jQuery.proxy`, or even better the `bind` method that is now included in the standard. If it's not available in some browser, it's easy to define one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018943/javascript-object-binding-problem-inside-of-function-prototype-definitions/3019431#3019431

Comment: Maybe this the "best approach" but I think its the most readable and less code.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways to do this.

Anurag has a perfect example of one.

Two other ways are the jQuery Proxy class (Mentioned in other answers) and the 'apply' function

Now lets create an object with click events:

```
var MyObj = function(){

this.property1 = "StringProp";

// jQuery Proxy Function
$(".selector").click($.proxy(function(){

  //Will alert "StringProp"
  alert(this.property1);
// set the 'this' object in the function to the MyObj instance


},this));


//Apply Function
//args are optional
this.clickFunction = function(arg1){
    alert(this.property1);
};

$(".selector").click(this.clickFunction.apply(this,"this is optional"));


};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the possibility of temporarily storing a reference to `this` (`self = this`, see Anurag's answer), since ES6 it is possible to use arrow functions for this problem. These have no "own" `this`.
This means that the "usual" object-related `this` can be accessed again within an arrow function within an event handler:

```
$("selector").click(() => {
    this.method_name();
});
```

Further information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?retiredLocale=de#cannot_be_used_as_methods

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?retiredLocale=de#using_call_bind_and_apply